# Erro de rota _wdt após instalar o Profiler numa estrutura básica do Symfony 4

Tags: php, framework, symfony, yaml, symfony4

Numa instalação básica do Symfony 4, diferente da instalação full, não vem com o debug Profiler - ferramenta de desenvolvimento que fornece informações detalhadas sobre a execução de qualquer pedido. Instalando-o logo em seguida: `composer require --dev symfony/profiler-pack`, ao atualizar o navegador um erro é exibido:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_wdt" as such route does not exist.").`

Não existe a rota. Estou procurando na documentação e tudo que sei atualmente é sobre a config em routing_dev.yaml, porém era em versões anteriores ao Symfony 4.
Lembrando que estou rodando o server embutido `php bin/console server:run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com problemas de permissão, o cache não estava sendo limpo. Após resolver o problema com as permissões, um simples: `bin/console cache:clear` resolveu o problema e a barra de debug do *Profiler* apareceu.